# How do I update a model List<string> in JavaScript ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, view, parameter-passing

I'm using a model that contains a List of string as follows:

```
 public List<string> _ActivityAccessLevel { get; set; }
```

I want change the value of each string by javscript and then pass data to controller.
So I defined list as hidden variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model._ActivityAccessLevel[i])
}
```

How can I change the _ActivityAccessLevel string in Javascript. I used the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
$("#_ActivityAccessLevel" + '[' + cuurentID + ']').val(cuurentID +100);
```

Comment: Look at the html your code generates! - its `id="_ActivityAccessLevel_#_"` (where `#` is the indexer)

Comment: But you could also give your inputs a class name and then just use `$(yourClassName).eq(cuurentID).vall(....);`

Comment: <input name="_ActivityAccessLevel[0]" type="hidden" value="Z" /> <input name="_ActivityAccessLevel[1]" type="hidden" value="Z" />

Comment: As I copied and nothing else generated in page source

Comment: Therefore there is no `id` attribute - you would need to add one or use the `[name=".."]` selector (or better use the code in my 2nd comment)

Comment: But if you remove the leading `_` from the property name so that its `public List<string> ActivityAccessLevel { get; set; }` then the correct html will be generated (i.e. `id="ActivityAccessLevel_0_"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements by selecting by name, iterating and changing the values like so (with comments):

```
$(function () {
    // Select all the elements with name starting with "_ActivityAccessLevel["
    var accessLevels = $("[name^='_ActivityAccessLevel[']");
    // Iterate the elements and change the value to value_100 (or a value of your choice)
    $.each(accessLevels, function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + "_" + 100);
    });
    // This is just to check that the values have actually changed in the DOM
    // as the value won't be changed in the html inspector
    // **This should be removed after checking**
    $.each(accessLevels, function () {
        console.log("+++++> " + $(this).attr("name") + " => " + $(this).val());
    });
});
```